# Boost threads and FFmpeg: Such simple code gives me error C2064. What I do wrong way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, boost, ffmpeg

I have some class file.h where public: `bool frameSendingFinished;` is defined.
So in class logic i create and encode video frame, now I want to send it to some server using ffmpeg. I want to send in separate thread so in one of my classes function (in file.cpp) I do:

```
  if (frameSendingFinished)
  {
      boost::thread UrlWriteFrame(url_context, (unsigned char *)pb_buffer, len);
  }

 ....// some other functions code etc.

     void VideoEncoder::UrlWriteFrame( URLContext *h, const unsigned char *buf, int size )
{
    frameSendingFinished =false;
    url_write (h, (unsigned char *)buf, size);
    frameSendingFinished =true;
}
```

it works with out creation of new thread. Commenting thread line makes it compile...

so error is `error c2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments`

So - what shall I do with my code to make boost work with in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
boost::thread UrlWriteFrame(url_context, (unsigned char *)pb_buffer, len);
```

you create a boost::thread object named UrlWriteFrame, and pass `url_context`, `pb_buffer` and `len` the the boost::thread constructor. One of boost::thread's ctors expects something callable (function pointer, function object) as the 1st argument, and forwards the other arguments to that function. In your example, it ends up trying something like:

```
url_context(pb_buffer, len);
```

which is probably what triggers the "does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments" error.

IIUC, you would like to call the `UrlWriteFrame` function in a new thread. The proper way to do that with boost::thread would be something like:

```
boost::thread (&VideoEncoder::UrlWriteFrame, this, url_context, (unsigned char *)pb_buffer, len);
```

(Assuming that this is called from one of VideoEncoder's methods)